# installed percona-xtrabackup package still getting innobackupex: command not found

Tags: mysql, backup, percona, innobackupex

I have to configure the incremental backup of MySQL, for that, I am using innobackupex.

Installed percona-xtrabackup-2.3.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm on centos7, still getting

innobackupex: command not found

Answer (score 3):

The name of the command has changed. Try using the command 'xtrabackup' .
It is located in /usr/bin

Comment: I struggled a lot, this solution finally worked. Thank you